# How to find my regional office contact?

Tags: support

I need to update my credentials for the various Sitecore websites.  I tried updating my info on https://portal.sitecore.net, but that seems to have done very little. In a couple of locations, I have seen messages indicating that I should contact "my regional office", but there is no help provided to find said office.  The main Sitecore site has contacts for sales, but this doesn't seem like something that sales would handle.  Where can I find the contact information for my regional office?

Comment: Honestly, I usually ping the chat window on the Sitecore site for things like this. It will be a sales type role that will answer bet they will be able able to answer your question.

Comment: This is a great question Ben. I have found the same issue. It's easy to find sales people for Sitecore, but the Regional Office contact is a bit different if you need to change things. In the past, it usually started with the sales people, and they direct you but that takes a long time. Nowadays, I typically start with Mark Van Alast and he can help steer you in the right direction to making changes on anything SItecore site related more quickly. Look for him on Slack or Twitter.

Comment: Maybe their contact us page could be helpful!
http://www.sitecore.net/company/contact-us

They have their offices, emails and phone numbers there.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you log in to the Partner Network portal at http://spn.sitecore.net you can see your regional contact at the top right corner of the site.

[image]

Comment: Having just gone independent, I don't get that anymore.  I actually can still login, but it shows my contact information there.  Weird.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this is indeed handled by sales.  It was someone from AM Sales Support at the main Sausalito office that helped me.  I asked the person who helped me what the preferred channel is, but have not yet received a response. I expect that contacting your regional sales office as listed at http://www.sitecore.net/en/company/contact-us will get you in contact with some one who can help.

**Update**

The person that helped me from AM Sales replied and said that, currently, the Chat with Sales feature on the main website is the preferred channel for this sort of request.  She also suggested that there would be some enhancements to the contact methods coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Sitecore Certified and you have linked your Sitecore account with Sitecore Partner then you can easily find this information on Sitecore Partner Portal.

Sitecore Partner URL - https://spn.sitecore.net

On this site in top-right corner, you find this info in dropdown.

To link Sitecore Portal account with Sitecore Partner you can do it from https://portal.sitecore.net